# How to fetch escaped string in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

For example, I have a table:

```
create table student (name varchar(20));

INSERT INTO student values('a\'a');
```

If I use `select name from student;`, I will get string `a'a`. If I use `SELECT quote(name) from student;` I will get `'a\'a'`, the escaped  string is processed. However, for

```
Insert into student values ('\n\n');
```

I use

```
select quote(name) from student;
```

and I don't get `'\n\n'`. The function quote don't work properly. So How can I get `'\n\n'` ?

What I want to achieve is that when I use

```
select name from student;
```

I get the string form '\n\n' instead of something like '

'; I just don't what \n to be displayed as new line in the scree.

Inserting \\n don't work because what I want is to insert into the table with values '\n', which is 0x0A in hex form. So when I use

```
Insert into student values (0x0A);
```

How can I select to get the string form '\n' instead of '

'.
I just don't want 0x0A to be displayed as new line in the screen.

Comment: The function does work properly - you are just using it for the wrong purpose. Please describe what you actually want to achieve, because that is quite unclear.

Comment: You're inserting line breaks (which \n is). You need to escape the escape character `\\n`

Comment: I have edited the question to show what I want to achieve.